# Connecting accessory for Arduino with RPi B+

Tags: wifi, arduino

I would like to know if there is any possibility to connect accessory for Arduino with RPi.

Exactly, I have Arduino WiFi Shield (http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoWiFiShield) and Raspberry Pi B+. I don't want to buy special wifi adapter for RPi and I would like to use this one for Arduino.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WiFi shield you mentioned is designed for Arduino only. Well, you can communicate with it using SPI protocol on Raspberry Pi, but it will not allow you to browse Internet unless you are going to write your own driver for it (and that will be very slow due to SPI protocol limitations).

USB WiFi dongles are pretty cheap today. If you just need it for Internet connection, I would suggest to buy that instead.